# How to make this javascript script work?

Tags: javascript

i'm quite new to javascript and coding. I was wondering if someone could put this random name generator from jsfiddle together into a single working file?
I just cant work out how to make it run, do i have to import some libraries or something?
I have a feeling if i get this working i might learn something, somehow.

Heres where i got the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/3gtDf/

Heres the script:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('h2').text(randomEl(adjectives)+' '+randomEl(nouns));
    selectElementContents($('h2')[0]);
});

function randomEl(list) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() *   . list.length);
    return list[i];
}

function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

var adjectives = ["adamant", "adroit", "amatory", "animistic", "antic", "arcadian", "baleful", "bellicose", "bilious", "boorish", "calamitous", "caustic", "cerulean", "comely", "concomitant", "contumacious", "corpulent", "crapulous", "defamatory", "didactic", "dilatory", "dowdy", "efficacious", "effulgent", "egregious", "endemic", "equanimous", "execrable", "fastidious", "feckless", "fecund", "friable", "fulsome", "garrulous", "guileless", "gustatory", "heuristic", "histrionic", "hubristic", "incendiary", "insidious", "insolent", "intransigent", "inveterate", "invidious", "irksome", "jejune", "jocular", "judicious", "lachrymose", "limpid", "loquacious", "luminous", "mannered", "mendacious", "meretricious", "minatory", "mordant", "munificent", "nefarious", "noxious", "obtuse", "parsimonious", "pendulous", "pernicious", "pervasive", "petulant", "platitudinous", "precipitate", "propitious", "puckish", "querulous", "quiescent", "rebarbative", "recalcitant", "redolent", "rhadamanthine", "risible", "ruminative", "sagacious", "salubrious", "sartorial", "sclerotic", "serpentine", "spasmodic", "strident", "taciturn", "tenacious", "tremulous", "trenchant", "turbulent", "turgid", "ubiquitous", "uxorious", "verdant", "voluble", "voracious", "wheedling", "withering", "zealous"];
var nouns = ["ninja", "chair", "pancake", "statue", "unicorn", "rainbows", "laser", "senor", "bunny", "captain", "nibblets", "cupcake", "carrot", "gnomes", "glitter", "potato", "salad", "toejam", "curtains", "beets", "toilet", "exorcism", "stick figures", "mermaid eggs", "sea barnacles", "dragons", "jellybeans", "snakes", "dolls", "bushes", "cookies", "apples", "ice cream", "ukulele", "kazoo", "banjo", "opera singer", "circus", "trampoline", "carousel", "carnival", "locomotive", "hot air balloon", "praying mantis", "animator", "artisan", "artist", "colorist", "inker", "coppersmith", "director", "designer", "flatter", "stylist", "leadman", "limner", "make-up artist", "model", "musician", "penciller", "producer", "scenographer", "set decorator", "silversmith", "teacher", "auto mechanic", "beader", "bobbin boy", "clerk of the chapel", "filling station attendant", "foreman", "maintenance engineering", "mechanic", "miller", "moldmaker", "panel beater", "patternmaker", "plant operator", "plumber", "sawfiler", "shop foreman", "soaper", "stationary engineer", "wheelwright", "woodworkers"];

$('button').click();
```

And the html:

```
<button>new name</button>
    <h2></h2>
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need jQuery because you're using it to select elements and you need to make sure your DOM is ready when the code first runs because it will be looking for the `h2` element.

Also, you have a typo in this line:

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() *   . list.length);                                   
               (that extra dot)     ^^^
```

Let's fix it and try it here:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('h2').text(randomEl(adjectives)+' '+randomEl(nouns));
    selectElementContents($('h2')[0]);
});

function randomEl(list) {
    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
    return list[i];
}

function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(el);
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
}

var adjectives = ["adamant", "adroit", "amatory", "animistic", "antic", "arcadian", "baleful", "bellicose", "bilious", "boorish", "calamitous", "caustic", "cerulean", "comely", "concomitant", "contumacious", "corpulent", "crapulous", "defamatory", "didactic", "dilatory", "dowdy", "efficacious", "effulgent", "egregious", "endemic", "equanimous", "execrable", "fastidious", "feckless", "fecund", "friable", "fulsome", "garrulous", "guileless", "gustatory", "heuristic", "histrionic", "hubristic", "incendiary", "insidious", "insolent", "intransigent", "inveterate", "invidious", "irksome", "jejune", "jocular", "judicious", "lachrymose", "limpid", "loquacious", "luminous", "mannered", "mendacious", "meretricious", "minatory", "mordant", "munificent", "nefarious", "noxious", "obtuse", "parsimonious", "pendulous", "pernicious", "pervasive", "petulant", "platitudinous", "precipitate", "propitious", "puckish", "querulous", "quiescent", "rebarbative", "recalcitant", "redolent", "rhadamanthine", "risible", "ruminative", "sagacious", "salubrious", "sartorial", "sclerotic", "serpentine", "spasmodic", "strident", "taciturn", "tenacious", "tremulous", "trenchant", "turbulent", "turgid", "ubiquitous", "uxorious", "verdant", "voluble", "voracious", "wheedling", "withering", "zealous"];
var nouns = ["ninja", "chair", "pancake", "statue", "unicorn", "rainbows", "laser", "senor", "bunny", "captain", "nibblets", "cupcake", "carrot", "gnomes", "glitter", "potato", "salad", "toejam", "curtains", "beets", "toilet", "exorcism", "stick figures", "mermaid eggs", "sea barnacles", "dragons", "jellybeans", "snakes", "dolls", "bushes", "cookies", "apples", "ice cream", "ukulele", "kazoo", "banjo", "opera singer", "circus", "trampoline", "carousel", "carnival", "locomotive", "hot air balloon", "praying mantis", "animator", "artisan", "artist", "colorist", "inker", "coppersmith", "director", "designer", "flatter", "stylist", "leadman", "limner", "make-up artist", "model", "musician", "penciller", "producer", "scenographer", "set decorator", "silversmith", "teacher", "auto mechanic", "beader", "bobbin boy", "clerk of the chapel", "filling station attendant", "foreman", "maintenance engineering", "mechanic", "miller", "moldmaker", "panel beater", "patternmaker", "plant operator", "plumber", "sawfiler", "shop foreman", "soaper", "stationary engineer", "wheelwright", "woodworkers"];

$('button').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>new name</button>
<h2></h2>
```

All good.

Comment: Thanks people. I got rid of the dot and included jquery but it still wont work. I think i need to know more about the DOM thing.
It will only display the button...

Comment: You're welcome. The DOM thing is that you either put the script after the HTML markup or use delayed loading (for example, using https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: No, i still have no idea how to put this code into an html file and make it work in a browser, im afraid. My brain is fried

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error here, remove `.`

```
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() *   . list.length);
```

Your demo : https://jsfiddle.net/3gtDf/409/

Answer (score 0):

you need to include JQuery library in the single file you create